# MacOS Mojave. Xlib error while compiling. fatal error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found

Tags: macos, x11

I just updated to Mojave. Before the update I was compiling a C program that used Xlib with the flags

```
-I/usr/X11R6/include -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11
```

as in

```
gcc -Wall -o l l.c graphics/graphics.c -I/usr/X11R6/include -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11
```

After the update it stoped working, and I get the error:  fatal error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found

Comment: AFAIK, you would only get X11 includes and libs by installing XQuartz and even then they would be in `/opt/X11`. I would suggest you reinstall XQuartz then check where they are...

Comment: What X package did you install? XQuartz? That has, for ages, installed to /opt/X11, not /usr/X11R6. There used to be a symlink from /usr/X11R6 to /opt/X11 but they stopped doing that a long time ago, too. There may still be a symlink /usr/X11.

Comment: Should I reinstall XQuartz then? Also how can I check where X11 is?

Comment: You could try looking for X11 with `find  /usr  /opt -type d -name X11`